# Excel formula to execute something if a cell has a value, if not, check for another cell's value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I have an excel file, that has the following information

| Name | Type | Type 2 | Date | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | A |  | 1;2 |  |
| Jon |  | A |  | 2;3 |

I'm trying to extract just the 1, and just the 2 in the Date, or 2 or 3 in Date 2 columns
So, if Type is A, then the formula would break and extract something from Date
But, If Type has another value, then I'd like to check for Type 2, and then run the formula on Date 2
I know it's kind of a mess

I have the following right now:

`=IF(OR(Type="On-Call", Type 2="On-Call"),LEFT(Date, SEARCH(";",Date,1)),"")`

This works when Type has the value A, but if it doesn't, then it just doesn't display anything

Basically what I THINK I'd need is
IF Type has value A, then run the code, but, if it does not, then check for Type 2, and if it has value A, then run the code on Date 2
But that nested IF is giving me some trouble too
I had something similar to this, but did not work:

`=IF(OR(Sheet1!H2="On-Call"),LEFT(Sheet1!L2, SEARCH(";",Sheet1!L2,1)),IF(Sheet1!I2="On-Call"),LEFT(Sheet1!K2, SEARCH(";",SHEET1!K2,1)),"")`

Anyone has any idea of how I could achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the following formula to your sheet/table/range. Drag it to fill the other cells.

```
=IF(B2="A",LEFT(D2,SEARCH(";",D2)-1),IF(C2="A",LEFT(E2,SEARCH(";",E2)-1)))
```

It compares Type (B2) to `A` with found, splits Date (D2). If not found, then compares Type2 (C2) to `A`. If found, splits Date2 (E2).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! Tried it, but I don't get a value, just a #VALUE! instead of a result

Comment: @masok Did you adapt it to suite your worksheet(s)/tables?

Comment: I did, I double checked. I'll keep trying, thanks for the help!

Comment: @masok Can you show a link (image) of the workseet and the error?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here it is: https://imgur.com/a/CH6hGEp
Basically, I have two sheets, I want to be able to paste data in the first one, that already has a specific format, and then on Sheet2, automatically take that data, and get what I need, in the fields that I need them to be

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach to this kind of problem is:

```
=IFERROR(  VLOOKUP(H2,B2:D3,3,FALSE),  VLOOKUP(H2,C2:E3,3,FALSE)  )
```

using your data in A1:E3 and the lookup value in cell H2.

You can use any workable lookup, `VLOOKUP` is used simply because it is familiar to most.

The idea is to use a lookup that will give an error with failure. If it succeeds, you get a valid result from examining column "Type" and returning from column "Date", in this case `1;2` and can do with it as you wish. If it fails (errors), the second lookup gets a valid result from examining column "Type 2" and returning from column "Date 2".

Of course, it just demonstrates that. Other things can stick a finger in. For example, there may be no match/es in either column. Another might be there's a match in BOTH columns, and you have some more involved way of picking which of the two you care most for which could complicate what gets returned. All sorts of things.

For versions older than `IFERROR`, one can use `ISERROR`:

```
=IF(  ISERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,B2:D3,3,FALSE)),  VLOOKUP(H2,C2:E3,3,FALSE),  VLOOKUP(H2,B2:D3,3,FALSE)  )
```

It does the same thing, just is longer to accommodate the less happy way of doing it. `ISERROR` goes back a long way so one or the other should serve.

If your lookup logic is more involved than what is presented, it may take more adaptation to fit, but it's a simple, easy to follow a year from now, approach.